# Proving a variable less than a constant

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-inequalities

I've been working on a math problem for a while and I've gotten to the point where I'm trying to prove the following

If

$$A(x, y) = B(x, y) = c_1\hat{x}$$
$$C(x, y) = D(x, y) = c_2\hat{y}$$
$$E(x, y) = F(x, y) = c_1c_2\widehat{xy}$$

Then can I prove that $x<c_1$ and $y<c_2$?

This isn't a homework problem, and I've been working on this problem for a very long time, but I'm not a mathematician and I'm not sure how I would even begin to figure this out if it's true.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! I edited your post but I'm not sure whether you meant to format your math symbols this way. Can you verify whether this is correct?

Comment: Thanks, I've been fiddling with the symbols, I'm not super familiar with TEX or LaTeX, but I think I got it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the original problem is, nor what all of the information is. Assuming that some information about $A,C$ and/or $E$ is either given or somehow required for this problem, let's see what information about $A,C$ and $E$ can be used to directly show your desired inequality.

We're trying to prove that $x < c_{1}$ and $y < c_{2}$. Suppose first that $x < c_{1}$. Working backwards, let's express this into terms of $A,C,E$ through multiplying both sides by $AC=E$:

$$ A(x,y)C(x,y)x < c_{1}E(x,y).$$

Simple as that. Show that $A(x,y)C(x,y)x < c_{1}E(x,y)$, or any algebraic manipulation of it such as $\frac{A(x,y)C(x,y)}{c_{1}} < \frac{E(x,y)}{x}$, and $x < c_{1}$ directly follows. Similarly, $y < c_{2}$ is equivalent to

$$A(x,y)C(x,y)y < c_{2}E(x,y).$$

Again, I'm not sure why $E$ is defined, since it is equal to $AC$, unless some information regarding $A,C,E$ is given. But these two conditions on $A,C,E$ prove your desired inequalities. Remember that given only the information you've provided in the question, there is no basis for the inequality.

Comment: @Tiny Tim, sorry! I mixed up $B$ with $C/D$, and $C$ with $E/F$. I'll fix that now.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, I haven't defined C at all in terms of A or B.  I suppose I can follow your general idea though, but I'm not quite sure how to get there as A, B, C, D, E, and F are expressed in general terms themselves.  I've only just discovered that A = B = c1 and C = D = c2, etc.  I don't as yet have any idea what A and B actually are.  This math problem originally stems from a 2D physics problem extended into 3 dimensions.  I wasn't expecting or anticipating the answer I got.  I just recognize that it is, and I need to deal with it.  In 2D, A(x) = B(x) = c and x<c. Thank you Calvin!

Comment: How do you gather that $A(x) = B(x) = c$? I thought that $A$ and $B$ are multivariable and that $A(x,y) = B(x,y) = c_{1}x$? At this point, I'd strongly recommend posting the original problem. If you do so, I'd be happy to help more.

Comment: In the 2D case, A(x) = B(x) = c.  The original problem is well documented and proven to be true, but I'm extending it into three dimensions and that's left me floundering at this part.  I'm very grateful for your help but the original problem is so long and intense and this part is so far in that I'm hesitant to post the whole, even generalizing it and changing the variables worries me for personal reasons.  Suffice it to say, if I can work this problem (going on 2 years now), I could finally lay to rest a torture of mine.  I will post a little more, should I create a new post to do so?